# spl_object_hash(): Argument #1 ($object) must be of type object, string given

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I can create a record but when editing it throws me the error
I can also see the log
but not edit it

```
spl_object_hash(): Argument #1 ($object) must be of type object, string given
```

twig part of the view

```
{% extends 'layouts/layoutmodal.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm">
    {{ form_row(form.created_at, { 'label': 'Fecha de Ingreso:' }) }}                   
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
    {{ form_row(form.nombrecliente, { 'label': 'Nombre Cliente' }) }}                   
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
    {{ form_row(form.nombrecomercio, { 'label': 'Nombre Comercio' }) }}                 
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
    {{ form_row(form.telefono) }}                   
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
    {{ form_row(form.email, { 'label': 'Correo Electronico' }) }}                   
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
        {{ form_row(form.documento, { 'label': 'Documento: RUC/DNI/CE' }) }}                    
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
        {{ form_row(form.departamento) }}                   
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
        {{ form_row(form.provincia) }}                  
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
        {{ form_row(form.distrito) }}                   
    </div>
```

Form controller used to edit all the data loaded in the operation

```
#[Route('ventas/{id}/editar', name: 'ventas/clientes/editar', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]

public function editar(Request $request, Cliente $cliente): Response
{
   

    
    $form = $this->createForm(ClienteType::class, $cliente);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    


    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('ventas');
        
    }

    return $this->render('ventas/clientes/editar.html.twig', [
        'cliente' => $cliente,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

entity has ManyToOne relationship I don't think you have problems there:
since I can add and delete without any problem...

```
namespace App\Entity\Ventas;

use App\Repository\Ventas\ProvinciaRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProvinciaRepository::class)
 */
class Provincia
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nombre;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Departamento::class, inversedBy="provincia")
 */
private $departamento;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Distrito::class, mappedBy="provincia")
 */
private $distrito;

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->nombre;
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->distrito = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->nombre = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getNombre(): ?string
{
    return $this->nombre;
}

public function setNombre(string $nombre): self
{
    $this->nombre = $nombre;

    return $this;
}

public function getDepartamento(): ?Departamento
{
    return $this->departamento;
}

public function setDepartamento(?Departamento $departamento): self
{
    $this->departamento = $departamento;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Distrito[]
 */
public function getDistrito(): Collection
{
    return $this->distrito;
}

public function addDistrito(Distrito $distrito): self
{
    if (!$this->distrito->contains($distrito)) {
        $this->distrito[] = $distrito;
        $distrito->setProvincia($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeDistrito(Distrito $distrito): self
{
    if ($this->distrito->removeElement($distrito)) {
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($distrito->getProvincia() === $this) {
            $distrito->setProvincia(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
}
```

Comment: SO is English-only. Translate the question or post at [es.so]

Comment: corrected @Barmar